# Disabling selected row in JQuery Datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

I have a data table in my project. Now i have the code to hide the row when click on the button in the row. The code is given below.

```
$('#SiteTable').on('click', '.edit', function () {
                var row = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
                var data = oTable1.fnGetData(row);
                var jqInputs = $('input', row);
                var jqTds = $('>td', row);
                var LineID = data[0];
                var Itm = data[1];
                var Quant = jqInputs[0].value;
                if (Quant > 0) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "StockAllocation/AllocateStock",
                        data: {
                            OrderRequestLineItemID: LineID,
                            Quantity: Quant,
                            Item: Itm

                        },
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function () { jqTds[4].innerHTML = "Allocated"; $(row).hide(); },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) { }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert("Please allot items.");
                }
            });
```

Instead of hiding the row, i want to disable the entire row. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: What does disabling involve? Usually there isn't much interaction with a table row, unless your situation is different? Can you explain what you're trying to do? Images would also help.

Comment: I have a button in the row. I want to disable the row to avoid further interaction with the button. I just need avoid clicking the button further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable all buttons for the row:

```
$(row).children("button").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```